# Drawing to a Canvas inside a ListView element

Tags: java, android, listview, canvas, adapter

I'm attempting to draw to a Canvas inside each element of a ListView. Currently I'm using the following code, which gives a Force Close as soon as I launch the activity:

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Activity
{   
    private ListView listView;
    private List<Row> listRows;

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.year);

        //Added initialisation from answers
        listRows = new ArrayList<Row>();

        //Add some generic rows to the list for test purposes
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            listRows.add(new Row(this));
        }

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
        listView.setAdapter(new RowAdapter(this, listRows));
    }
}
```

**RowAdapter.java**

```
public class RowAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private List<Row> elements;
    private Context context;

    public RowAdapter(Context c, List<Row> rows) {
        this.elements = rows;
        this.context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return elements.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return elements.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return elements.get(position);
    }
}
```

**Row.java**

```
public class Row extends View 
{
    public Row(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //Draw simple string as an example
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawText("Text here...", 0, 0, paint);
    }
}
```

I realise there are probably many problems with my approach to this, so if anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be grateful.

Thanks for your help in advance.

**EDIT:** The ListView now loads but shows no elements. I'm using the main.xml file shown below.

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `listRows = new ArrayList<Row>();` to initialize the list before adding elements to it.

In general, try examining the output of logcat in your Eclipse debug perspective or in ddms. In this case it would've said something to the effect of "null pointer in onCreate" and you would've saved yourself some time.

**Edit** I suspect this is because your Row views don't know how big they should be. You might try overriding `onMeasure` with a simple method as a sanity check:

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
   setMeasuredDimension(100, 100);
}
```

The need to do this can be mitigated by some better factoring of your code. The underlying data of an Adapter isn't meant to touch views directly; generally the views are created in `getView`.

For instance, you might have in `res/layout/row.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.HelloCanvas
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    ... other attributes like background color ...
    />
```

This way you can set xml properties on your custom view, which is nice if you use it in multiple places.

Then HelloCanvas would define the `HelloCanvas(Context, AttributeSet)` constructor, which the layout inflater utilizes:

```
public HelloCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

And finally your `getView` method would inflate `row.xml`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    HelloCanvas hello = (HelloCanvas) convertView;
    if (hello == null) {
        // inflate a new view
        hello = (HelloCanvas) 
          LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    }
    hello.setHelloString(getItem(position));
    return hello;
}
```

This way you aren't generating new views if you don't have to, and the underlying data type of your ArrayAdapter (eliminates some of your excess code) can be String.

Comment: Slow down please so I can get some too :p

Comment: Well... your answer is more complete... if I were the guy I would choose yours as correct.

Comment: @Cristian & Matthew: Cheers for the rapid answers :) You're right, I should definitely have checked logcat, I just assumed I had many problems with my code.That certainly fixes the force close, but the list elements don't seem to display at all. Do I need to add something to the XML file. I've added this to my original question. Thanks again.

Comment: Overriding onMeasure worked. Thanks for the suggestions on how to improve the code, I'll definitely try and rewrite it using this structure. Thanks again.